# Python combinational algorithmic program to return sublist of a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to write a program to return sublist of a list i.e. for a list `[1,2,3]`, the program should return `[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3] and [1,2,3]`.

I know of the concept of dictionary as well apart from list. So, can somebody instruct me on how i can solve this problem so that I could implement the same concept in other similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
  xs = list(iterable)
  # note we return an iterator rather than a list
  return chain.from_iterable( combinations(xs,n) for n in range(len(xs)+1) )

>>> list(powerset([1,2,3]))
[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

If you don't want the empty element:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 1, powerset([1,2,3])))
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Isn't there other way to do this without importing anything ? Just by using for loop or recursion ?

Comment: @ShrijanAryal of course, but I'm not sure why you would do that.

Comment: Is this homework, or you're just trying to understand how the algorithm would work?

Comment: I was practicing coding interview questions in hackerrank and I had to apply a logic of this type to the problem. So that is why i wanted to know because these types of programs are very common.

Comment: Ah, well the method above uses the standard library, which means it is available anywhere python is available (assuming you're using a new enough version of python). So, not using it would be wrong, since this is the correct way to do this in python.

Comment: Your question is like saying "how can I do addition in Java without using the + operator" since these are _normal_ python functions that you should be familiar with.